# WebClient causes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task" in JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient

I wanted to use reactive programming inside the JUnit testing framework to do system tests on a remote rest api.

I thus wrote:

```
  @Test
  void testWebClient() {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(GITHUB_API_BASE_URL)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, GITHUB_V3_MIME_TYPE)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, USER_AGENT)
        .filter(ExchangeFilterFunctions
            .basicAuthentication(appProperties.getGithub().getUsername(),
                appProperties.getGithub().getToken()))
        .build();

    var response = webClient.get()
        .uri("/user/repos?sort={sortField}&direction={sortDirection}",
            "updated", "desc")
        .exchange()
            .doOnError(e -> {
              System.out.println(e.toString());
            })
            .subscribe(r -> {
              System.out.println(r  );
            });
  }
```

to get all my github repos. I kept catching this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task
```

until add ".block()" after ".exchange()" to do the call synchronously and everything start to work fine.

I suspect JUnit to start a special thread context or something like that. Do you know what can is happening?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that once the function `testWebClient()` finish, all the asynchronous process are closed.

In this case you are using `WebClient` that is an async job, so the function `testWebClient()` finish before the `WebClient` can get the answer.

In order to prevent this, you can:

- use a thread sleep method like `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)`.
- use an external library like [`Awaitility`](http://www.awaitility.org/)

**Example with Awaitility**

```
bool taskDone = false;
@Test
void testWebClient() {
    //...
    var response = webClient.get()
    //...
    .doFinally(r->{
        taskDone = true;
    })

    await().until(()-> taskDone);
}
```

So in this case the function will wait until the task complete.

Comment: Another option to using sleep or an external library is to just make the web client call a blocking call. Your code could be something like this:
`var resp = webClient.get().uri(url).retrieve().toEntity(String.class).block();
assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, resp.getStatusCode());`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use StepVerifier in your test case.

```
    StepVerifier.create(<flux>)
      .expectSubscription()
      .consumeNextWith(e-> log.debug(e.toString()))      
      .thenAwait().verifyComplete();
```

will need the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```